# Как перевернуть изображение?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Как перевернуть фотографию загруженную на сервер, по клику на кнопку `+90` или `-90` градусов.Фотографии находятся на сервере, поэтому мне нужно чтобы картинка перевернулась как на странице так и на сервере.

[image: Пример]

```css
.con_img {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background: #FFD140;
  border: 1px solid #FFC000;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 210px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5x;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 30px;
}
.img {
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 140px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 0px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
.but {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  background: #999;
  width: 30px;
  float: left;
  margin: 6px 28px;
  padding: 0px 6px;
}
.but:hover {
  background: #777;
}
```

```html
<div class="con_img">
  <div id="rotate_minuc" class="but">- 90</div>
  <div id="rotate_plus" class="but">+ 90</div>

  <img src="http://img.bibo.kz/?300x6717935.jpg" class="img" />
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rfjdkrj9/

Comment: Вместо jsfiddle, пожалуйста, используйте встроенные js-сниппеты. Так этот код будет 1) храниться в самом вопросе и 2) выполняться в самом вопросе.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin Спасибо. Исправил, добавил код в вопрос.

Comment: отлично, плюс вам )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ссылку на jsfiddle всё равно имеет смысл в вопросе оставлять, чтобы в случае желания поэкспериментировать у отвечающего была возможность ей воспользоваться.

Comment: @Qwertiy разумное предложение, в будущем буду рекомендовать именно так делать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простой пример, как перевернуть картинку ( на 90, 180 , 270 градусов ) и сохранить на сервере. Если нужно фото перевернуть и просто заменить, поставь одинаковые имена, картинки которую вращаешь и новой картинки, тогда новая картинка заменит старую.

php:

```
    $image = 'image/image.jpg';
$new_image = 'image/new_image.jpg';

$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);    // Картинка
    $degrees = 90;                         //Наклон картинки
    $imgRotated = imagerotate($img, $degrees, 0);
    imagejpeg($imgRotated, $new_image, 90);  //  Новая картинка
```

Вывод html:

```
<img src="image/image.jpg"/> ..... <img src="image/new_image.jpg">
```

Фото примера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

На стороне клиента перевороты очень легко реализуются с помощью css-свойства `transform:rotate(Xdeg)`. Только надо не забыть, что это свойство не меняет слои, поэтому надо предусмотреть изменение внешней обертки под новый размер.

На стороне сервера это хорошо выполнит функция [imagerotate()](http://www.php.su/imagerotate).

Можно сделать еще так:

1. при клике на элемент страницы, отвечающий за поворот создаем `iframe`, который запрашивает, допустим rotate.php и несет в своих параметрах `url` изображения и угол поворота;
2. `php` переворачивает картинку, сохраняет ее на сервере и возвращает во фрейм;
3. заменяем исходную картинку, новой

Comment: Не знаю почему, но на 'Денвере', картинка переворачивается только в браузере, а сама картинка не меняет свой угол.

Comment: @Muson, не забывайте после поворота картинки на сервере ее сохранить.

Comment: Не могу понять как сохранить картинку после переворота. Смотрел разные примеры  ( php.net/manual/ru/function.imagerotate.php ) ,  но не нашел ответ.

Comment: ...ну или делать это на сервере посредством imagemagick

Comment: @11111000000 А вы всегда монитором крутите, когда картинка плохо отображается на мониторе. Хотел бы я это видеть.

Comment: @Muson, вы выбрали правильный ответ, видимо Вам уже не важно сохранение )